# Why does a subclass of an inner class require an enclosing instance?

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

Consider class `OuterClass` which has `InnerClass`

```
public class OuterClass {
    class InnerClass {

    }
}
```

And the second class, which is trying to extend `InnerClass` of `OuterClass`

```
public class Clazz extends OuterClass.InnerClass {
    public Clazz(OuterClass outerClass) {
        outerClass.super();
    }
}
```

So far so good, this code will work, compiler should not give warnings.

But I am trying to understand - why is that necessary to pass to constructor reference of *OuterClass*? and why is that necessary to call it's super constructor?

I want to understand why is it has to be exact this way?

Also, consider this class (not related to previous ones) in which classes `Apartments` and `Hall` are inner classes to `Building` class which is inner to `Solution` (innerception).

```
public class Solution {
    public class Building {
        public class Hall {
            private BigDecimal square;

            public Hall(BigDecimal square) {
                this.square = square;
            }
        }

        public class Apartments {
        }
    }
}
```

Then there goes top-level class which is trying to extend inner inner class Hall

```
class BigHall extends Solution.Building.Hall {
    public BigHall(Solution.Building building, BigDecimal square)
    {
        building.super(square);
    }
}
```

Look at this mess. Last two classes should compile as well, but can you clear it up for me, why `BigHall` class when extending inner inner class `Hall` does need to pass to constructor reference to Building object instead of Solution object?

If you can provide quotation from JLS that'd be great!

Comment: Because `InnerClass` is not `static` is has an implicit reference to its parent `OuterClass` instance. I have absolutely no idea why one would do any of this however - if you're nesting classes 3 deep something has gone _very_ wrong.

Comment: A top-level class should not extend a nested class, especially not an inner class. Inner-class instances can only live within instances of their containing class.

Comment: I think if you feel you need to do this, InnerClass should not be an inner class. I think you'd better make use of [packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) .

Comment: [JLS §8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

Comment: You should really use composition instead of what you are trying to accomplish there.

Comment: I should clear this out: it's not a real usecase, question is asked for academical interest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `InnerClass` is an [*inner class*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

> An *inner class* is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly
>   declared `static`.

Inner classes may have enclosing instances

> An instance `i` of a direct inner class `C` *[your `InnerClass`]* of a
>   class or interface `O` *[your `OuterClass`]* is associated with an
>   instance of `O`, known as the *immediately enclosing instance of `i`*.

Only inner classes declared in static contexts don't have enclosing instances.

> An instance of an inner class `I` whose declaration occurs in a static
>   context has no lexically enclosing instances.

Your example's inner class is not in a static context and **therefore requires an enclosing instance.**

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.1) then states

> The constructor of a non-private inner member class implicitly
>   declares, as the first formal parameter, a variable representing the
>   immediately enclosing instance of the class

(It goes into further detail as to why, if you're interested). In other words, your `InnerClass` constructor really looks like

```
public InnerClass(OuterClass OuterClass.this){} // this is valid syntax for entirely different reasons
```

It expects an argument of type `OuterClass` to use as its enclosing instance. Subclassing this `InnerClass` type does not change that, especially since any subtype must invoke its supertype's super constructor.

On the subject of constructors, the [specification also states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7)

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor
>   invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the
>   primordial class `Object`, **then the constructor body implicitly begins
>   with a superclass constructor invocation "super();"**, an invocation of
>   the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

So obviously, without the parameter, your code wouldn't work

```
public class Clazz extends OuterClass.InnerClass {
    public Clazz() {
        // implicit super() invocation
    }
}
```

This `super()` constructor invocation wouldn't work. In this case, it's because it's the wrong syntax. But the idea is that the super constructor is expecting an argument for the formal parameter representing the enclosing instance, but you aren't providing one. The correct syntax is the one you already have. Let's define it.

There are [multiple kinds of constructor invocations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1). Yours

```
public Clazz(OuterClass outerClass) {
    outerClass.super();
}
```

is a *qualified superclass constructor invocation*, [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1) as

> *Qualified superclass constructor invocations* begin with a `Primary`
>   expression or an `ExpressionName`. **They allow a subclass constructor to
>   explicitly specify the newly created object's immediately enclosing
>   instance with respect to the direct superclass (§8.1.3). This may be
>   necessary when the superclass is an inner class.**

The [chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1) goes one to explain how the expression is evaluated

> If the superclass constructor invocation is qualified, then the
>   `Primary` expression or the `ExpressionName` immediately preceding
>   "`.super`", `p`, is evaluated.
>   [...]
>
> Otherwise, the result of this evaluation is the **immediately enclosing
>   instance of `i` with respect to `S`**.

In other words, the object referenced by `outerClass` becomes the required *enclosing instance* of your `Clazz` instance.

---

In simplified terms, ignoring the case of inner classes, your example boils down to something like

```
public class Foo {}
public class Bar {
    public Bar(Foo foo){}
}
public class SubBar extends Bar {
    public SubBar(Foo foo) {
        super(foo);
    }
}
```

`SubBar` has to satisfy the `Bar` super constructor that expects a `Foo` instance. This is the same thing that's happening with your `Clazz` type except its super type's constructor is implicit.

Answer (score 3):

*why is that necessary to pass to constructor reference of OuterClass?*

Simply because an instance of `InnerClass` can exist only within an instance of `OuterClass` and has direct access to the methods and fields of its enclosing instance. This is how inner (non-static) classes [are designed in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

**UPD** As you asked for JLS reference, Dear @Boris the Spider provides it twice in commentaries, it is [JLS 8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3). But I personally find JLS description of this thing quite messy. Official Java Doc tutorials give explanation of these things in more easy way.

Comment: OP asked for a JLS reference - as per my comment this is [JLS §8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you, I've added link and mentioned you in my answer

Comment: I did not downvote this answer, and I actually disagree with the DV because the answer answers the question. *But*: I have the feeling this is kind of X-Y. I have the feeling that OP is misusing the inner class concept.

Comment: @Fildor Well, he asked the question *why*, and I think I gave an answer. Thank you for your support.

Comment: That's what I said: You answer the question. Still I would find it "nice" for the OP to be hinted to see his misconception. But that's not necessary for the answer to be at least *not* downvoted ... just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following

```
public class Outer {
    String outerString;

    class Inner { 
        public void doStuff() {
            System.out.println("Outer string is " + outerString);
        }
    }


    static class StaticInner { 
        public void doStuff() {
            // can't access outerString here
        }
    }
}
```

In this example... each `Inner` needs an `Outer` to exist. `Inner` can access all fields from `Outer`

But `StaticInner` does not need an `Outer` to exist. It cannot access the fields from `Outer`

Comment: I have the feeling that OP's confusion comes from the misconception that inner classes serve the purpose of "grouping" classes in the way it is done by packages. I *think* he should be using packages instead.

Answer (score 0):

An inner class can be extended by another class outside of it’s outer class. If you are extending static inner class (Static nested class), then it is a straight forward implementation. If you are extending non-static inner class, then sub class constructor must explicitly call super class constructor using an instance of outer class. Because, you can’t access non-static inner class without the instance of outer class.

**Sample Code**

```
    class OuterClass
{
    class InnerClassTwo
    {
        //Class as a non-static member
    }
}

//Extending non-static inner class or member inner class
class AnotherClassTwo extends OuterClass.InnerClassTwo
{
    public AnotherClassTwo()
    {
        new OuterClass().super();  //accessing super class constructor through OuterClass instance
    }
}
```

**Internal code generated by the compiler**

```
class Outer$Inner  
{  
    final Outer this$0;  
    Outer$Inner()  
    {   super();  
        this$0 = Outer.this;  
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a `static` inner class.